# Conditional Formatting is being re-created when sheet is activated - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have code on a worksheet on excel that is run every time the worksheet is activated 
`Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`. I have a code for conditional formatting but every time the worksheeet is activated, it re-creates the same format again and again.  How do I code this so if the conditional format already exists, do nothing?

Any help will be appreciated!

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Comparison w. Agg Loss Code: Conditional Formatting

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim LastRowAgg As Long
Dim LastColumnAgg As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


With wb.Sheets("Comparison w. Agg Loss")

    .Select
    'Format to 3 decimal places
    LastRowAgg = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumnAgg = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(LastRowAgg, LastColumnAgg)).NumberFormat = "0.000"

    'Formula for conditional formatting
    .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(LastRowAgg, LastColumnAgg)).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=AND((ABS('Input Correlation'!B5:AT" & LastRowAgg & "-'Aggregate Loss Correlation'!B5:AT" & LastRowAgg & ")/'Input Correlation'!B5:AT" & LastRowAgg & ")>=(1/3),B5:AT" & LastRowAgg & "<>"" "")"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

end with

end sub
```

Comment: Instead of Worksheet_Activate you may consider using Workbook_Open event.

Comment: @Santosh When I do that and exit out of the file and open it up again, same thing happens.  The formatting is re-created when the file is open again....Do I have to write special code in a Workbook_Open event to stop that from happening?

Comment: Show us the code you already have.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test to see if `FormatConditions.Count` is greater than 0.